# How to update file permission uploaded on bucket of AWS S3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I uploading videos using Multipart Upload to Amazon-S3 using the node.js. I am using [this](https://gist.github.com/sevastos/5804803) reference

The uploaded video by default is only accessible to owner.

When uploading file using below code

var params_to_upload_on_S3 = {
                    ACL: 'public-read',
                    Bucket: imageBucket,
                    Key: imgName  + ".jpg",
                    Body: imageBuffer,
                    ContentType : 'Image/jpg'
                }

```
        s3.putObject(params_to_upload_on_S3 , function (err, res) {
            if(err)
                console.log('Thumnail Upload Error'+ err);
            else 
                console.log('Thumbnail Successfully uploaded .'+ JSON.stringify(res));

            fs.unlink(imagePath, function(){
                console.log('File deleted from local storage');
            });

        });
```

Comment: Did you check your directory at the bucket? Is it public?

Comment: yes bucket is set to public. But when I upload any file it is only access default to owner.